# Passing variable to a directive and DRY?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have some piece of code (not mine) which contains a directive with declared `scope` mapping. My wish is to use the directive in other place and pass additional variables which will be used within the template.

The variable I want to pass is `theVar`.

The only solution I found out to be working looks nightmarish:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('theFoo', [])

  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.theVar = true;
  }])

  .directive('aDirective', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        'someVarThatWasHereBefore': '=',
        'theVar': '='
      },
      template: '<p ng-show="theVar">You have successfully passed a boolean value!</p>'
    };
  });

})(window.angular);
```

```html
<body ng-app="theFoo">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <a-directive data-the-var="theVar"></a-directive>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there any way to do it without repeating the name of my variable **four times** within the `scope` and the HTML element?

Comment: You can use a function that returns a function (that returns the directive object literal definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks fine.  As for repeating the name of the variable four times - that is how angular works to define directives, pass data to them, and use the data in the template.

It is not against DRY principles to define and pass variables around.  DRY is more about not rewriting blocks of logic.

To be clear on naming of variables - the variable you pass into the directive does not need to match its name in the directive scope.

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('theFoo', [])

  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = true;
  }])

  .directive('aDirective', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        'someVarThatWasHereBefore': '=',
        'theVar': '='
      },
      template: '<p ng-show="theVar">You have successfully passed a boolean value!</p>'
    };
  });

})(window.angular);
```

```html
<body ng-app="theFoo">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <a-directive data-the-var="myVar"></a-directive>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I understand that directive acts as a kind of a higher-level function and the `scope` mapping is that function's signature. With the odd exception that absence of signature passes entire outer scope contents to the directive. Do I get it right?

Comment: Ya sort of, but I don't think comparing them to functions is really accurate - they are UI elements that have logic functions built in.  **Think of scope as a context.**  Some directives will need to have a private context (*isolated scope*), other directives will need to inherit their context.  *"absence of signature passes entire outer scope contents"* - not exactly, it just uses the exact scope object of the containing element.  If you use `scope: true`, each instance gets its own unique scope that is initialized with (*inherits*) everything from the containing element's scope.